# Proxy + SSL: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, proxy, certificate

I did own light version of HTTP client and have an issue with connection via proxy. The proxy works fine in a browser but won't work in my app.

When I am reading a stream:

```
private void OnStreamRead(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    int read = _stream.EndRead(ar);
```

I receive a next exception on EndRead:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   System.dll
>
> Additional information: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the
>   transport stream.

This exception appear only for https web-site and only with certain proxies.

I found that some problems can be in .net while authentication with a server.
I tried all possible combinations of Protocol types:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host, new X509CertificateCollection(), SslProtocols.Tls11, false);
```

Authenticate looks like that:

```
if (clientRequest.IsSSLConnection)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
    var sslStream = new SslStream(serverStream, false,
    HttpHelper.AcceptAllCertificationsCallback);
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host, new X509CertificateCollection(), SslProtocols.Tls11, false);

    serverStream = sslStream;
}
```

Any other ideas what I can try to do?